# unrecognized selector sent to class , in iphone5s ios8.2

Tags: objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oruhr.png)

Try to modify the global navigation, iphone6 and 6plus in 7 and 7plus no problem. Only in the iphone5s will appear on this error, the 5S is the ios8.2 system, I do not know why not ios8.2, because I have only this one ios8 mobile phone, the rest is ios10 in this problem.

How can I solve it?

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1993c6858'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Code:

```
@interface MainNavC ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, assign)BOOL isPaySuccuss;
@end

@implementation MainNavC

+ (void)load
{
    UINavigationBar *bar = [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[self class]]];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17],
                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                           };
    [bar setTitleTextAttributes:dict];

    [bar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>⌘-click</kbd> on the symbol then you will see

> NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);

That means the API is not available in iOS 8.

You could use this older class method for iOS 8.

```
+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedIn:(nullable Class <UIAppearanceContainer>)ContainerClass,  ...
```